# IBM BAW 22 - process portal - display all tasks

Tags: websphere, business-process-management, ibm-bpm

I have a very big problem after migrating BPM from version 8.5.5 to BAW 22. I have a saved search on the process portal, which shows me the tasks of all users broken down by process. After migration, this search has stopped working and it only shows me my tasks and the team tasks I belong to. It stopped showing other users tasks. I tried to fix this error in different ways but nothing works. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more specifics on what you have tried so far?

Two things I would suggest:

1. If search optimization is enabled, check out this link here if you haven't already. You will need to drop the LSW_BPD_INSTANCE_VAR_NAMES and LSW_BPD_INSTANCE_VARS_PIVOT tables and recreate them using the steps mentioned here:
   https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/baw/22.x?topic=portal-tuning-process-searches

2)Depending on your Saved Search criteria, it's possible you will need to re-create it.  See the red alert section about existing saved searches and migration here:
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/baw/22.x?topic=windows-restarting-verifying-migration.
It mentions 'earlier versions of Business Automation Workflow' but the same would apply to earlier versions of BPM